# Floating 2 individual html tables side by side

Tags: html, css, compare

I am making a compare engine, and i made a dropdown system (not much, but it is a begin). My question is: how do you put 2 individual html tables (From different files) side by side, so you can choose which tables you want side by side so you can compare the 2 products! this is an example of what i mean: https://gyazo.com/85c8ee29a6723828d3ded529cd4cce87

Thanks!

Comment: use grid system from bootstrap. it allows you to format your data as you want

Comment: Have you considered just rendering the columns you need from each table into a third table (or appending them to the other table) ?

Comment: i am not familiar with bootstrap. isnt there a way in html that you can click on a option in the dropdown and that it shows a different table? (so if you have 2 dropdown menus that you can compare 2 different tables that you selected?)

Answer (score 0):

Take two divs and insert table both and write css like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .first
            {
                float:left;
                width:48%;
                margin-right:2%;
            }
            .second
            {
                float:left;
                width:50%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="first">
            <table border="1" style="width:100%">
                <tr>
                    <td>Jill</td>
                    <td>Smith</td>      
                    <td>50</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Eve</td>
                    <td>Jackson</td>        
                    <td>94</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>John</td>
                    <td>Doe</td>        
                    <td>80</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="first">
            <table border="1" style="width:100%">
                <tr>
                    <td>Jill</td>
                    <td>Smith</td>      
                    <td>50</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Eve</td>
                    <td>Jackson</td>        
                    <td>94</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>John</td>
                    <td>Doe</td>        
                    <td>80</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, but i meant that i want to make options with a drop down menu, so when you click on a option a different table will be shown. i made a dropdown menu, but how do you make it, that if you click on a option a different table will be shown, that if you have 2 dropdown menus, you can select different tables to compare

Comment: Use jQuery to fetch selected option from dropdown and on the basis of that display table.

Comment: i am not very familiar with jQuery... do you have a link to a tutorial?